# values in this csv are not being edited - Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, if-statement, foreach, export-to-csv

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\scripts\door-system\test\testChange.csv" -Encoding UTF8
$users | ft

$output = forEach ($user in $users)
{
     if ($user.GroupName -like "Normal")
    {
        $output.GroupName = "edited"
    }
}

$output | export-csv .\modified.csv -noTypeInformation
```

Comment: if you want `$output` to see your changes, you need to only make updates to `$user.groupname` in your loop

Comment: What kind of output do you get and what do you expect. Any error massages? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AdminOfThings it is not in the assignment it will just print the state of `$users`

Comment: If the groupname is "Normal" you should use `-eq` instead of `-like`. Otherwise you might use `-like "Normal*"` .. with the star! ;-)  And you should assign the new value to **$User.GroupName** not to **$output.GroupName**

Answer (score 1):

you have two glitches in your code. [*grin*]

the 1st is modifying the `$Output` collection inside the loop AND assigning the output of the loop to the `$Output` collection. do one or the other, not both.

the 2nd is not outputting anything to put in the `$Output` collection. that will give you an empty collection since you assigned *nothing at all* to it.

here's my version & what it does ...

- fakes reading in a CSV file
  when you are ready to do this with real data, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and use `Import-CSV`.
- sets the target and replacement strings
- iterates thru the imported collection
- tests for the target in the `.GroupName` property of each object
- if found, it replaces that value with the replacement string
- sends the modified object out to the `$Results` collection
- displays `$Results` on screen
- saves $Results to a CSV file

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a CSV file
#    in real life, use Import-CSV
$UserList = @'
UserName, GroupName
ABravo, Normal
BCharlie, Abnormal
CDelta, Other
DEcho, Normal
EFoxtrot, Edited
FGolf, Strange
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv
#endregion >>> fake reading in a CSV file

$TargetGName = 'Normal'
$ReplacementGName = 'Edited'

$Results = foreach ($UL_Item in $UserList)
    {
    if ($UL_Item.GroupName -eq $TargetGName)
        {
        $UL_Item.GroupName = $ReplacementGName
        }
    # send the modified data to the $Results collection
    $UL_Item
    }

# show on screen
$Results

# send to CSV
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\Connor Tuohy_-_Modified.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

on screen output ...

```
UserName GroupName
-------- ---------
ABravo   Edited   
BCharlie Abnormal 
CDelta   Other    
DEcho    Edited   
EFoxtrot Edited   
FGolf    Strange
```

CSV file ["C:\Temp\Connor Tuohy_-_Modified.csv"] content ...

```
"UserName","GroupName"
"ABravo","Edited"
"BCharlie","Abnormal"
"CDelta","Other"
"DEcho","Edited"
"EFoxtrot","Edited"
"FGolf","Strange"
```